# Transforming an icon animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to create my own icon transform animation that is an right facing arrow when a menu is closed and an x when opened. It looks like something I am trying to achieve apart from the fact it's changing its position when animating.

I wanted the growing yellow lines making the x to be smoothly animated in as well instead of moving the icon around slightly to the left or right.

[image]

I couldn't find a good example online myself so decided to make this. I can't properly animate it, could someone point me in the right direction.

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.menu = {
    opened: false
  };
  
  vm.toggleMenu = function() {
    vm.menu.opened = !vm.menu.opened;
  }
  
})
```

```css
.close-x {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 27px 0 22px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-x:before, .close-x:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 14px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #426294;
}
.close-x:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.close-x:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.close-x.arrow-x:before,
.close-x.arrow-x:after {
  height: 8px;
  top: 11px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.close-x.arrow-x:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(3px,-3px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(3px,-3px);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="close-x" ng-class="{'arrow-x': !vm.menu.opened}" ng-click="vm.toggleMenu()"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your result's working fine on my firefox browser. Pretty smooth though.

Comment: It is smooth but what triggers me is that it's moving to the left when transforming into x and to the right when transforming into arrow. It doesn't stand still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it moves because you're manipulating the height to give off that animation, if you want the animation to be visual, you must never play with the dimensions.

Here's a solution animating the background

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function() {var vm = this; vm.menu = {opened: false }; vm.toggleMenu = function() {vm.menu.opened = !vm.menu.opened; } })
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(5);
  padding-left:46%;
  padding-top:20px;
  /* ignore, just to zoom in*/
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.close-x {
  position: relative;
  /*   padding: 0 27px 0 22px; */
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid;
} 

.close-x:before,
.close-x:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 14px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 50%;
  /* instead of padding on the parent*/
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /* to center horizontally */
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #426294;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #426294, #426294) 0px 0px/100% 100% no-repeat;
}

.close-x:before {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.close-x:after {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.close-x.arrow-x:before,
.close-x.arrow-x:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #426294, #426294) 0px 0px/2px 8px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
    <div class="close-x" ng-class="{'arrow-x': !vm.menu.opened}" ng-click="vm.toggleMenu()"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**EDIT: i made a new one from scratch because it'll be faster than fixing your own, it animates the width which should work in IE**

```css
div {
  /* height and width can be changed but they have to match*/
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 20%;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}

div:before {
  bottom: 0;
  background: orange;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: translateY(25%) rotate(-45deg);
}

div:after {
  background: orange;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}

div:hover:before,
div:hover:after {
  width: 69%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hover over it.</h1>
<div></div>
```

**Note:** if you change the thickness, which is the height of the pseudo-Elements, you'll to adjust the mid section where they shrink too, if you don't understand what i'm saying try changing the height and you'll understand.

Comment: I'm not sure, i always just ignore IE because we want it dead

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the `transition` property in the original css class without the `:after` or `:before` selectors:

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.menu = {
    opened: false
  };
  
  vm.toggleMenu = function() {
    vm.menu.opened = !vm.menu.opened;
  }
  
})
```

```css
.close-x {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 27px 0 22px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.close-x:before, .close-x:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 14px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #426294;
}
.close-x:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.close-x:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.close-x.arrow-x:before,
.close-x.arrow-x:after {
  height: 8px;
  top: 11px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.close-x.arrow-x:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(3px,-3px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(3px,-3px);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="close-x" ng-class="{'arrow-x': !vm.menu.opened}" ng-click="vm.toggleMenu()"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```